# Calculate statistics on numbers entered by user

Tags: algorithm, logic, calculation

This was my tutorial given by the lecturer. I don't understand the question. I need guidance into the right direction.

> Write an algorithm to read in a list of basketball scores (non-negative integers) one at a time from the user and output the following statistics:
>
> 1. Total number of games.
> 2. Total number of games scoring at least 90 points.
> 3. Percentage of games scoring at least 90 points.
>
> The user entering a negative sentinel value indicates the end of the input. Note that the sentinel value is not used in computing the highest, lowest or average game score.
>
> #### Requirements:
>
> - Write pseudo code for how you would solve each statistic
>
>   - Example: total number of games
>   - For each input score, increment
>       games by one
> - Determine the variables you will need and figure out the type of each variable
> - Define and initialize each variable
> - Determine what type of loop you are going to write
> - Start with statistic number one (total number of games) and get your loop to compute the total number of games. When you end your loop,
>     output the total number of games, and then move to problem two.
> - You only need to write **one** loop.
> - Write a **complete** algorithm for the above problem.

I've tried to understand the requirement and tried googling for some alternative language but unable to find so

```
n = 0 // number of games
o = 0 // total number of games scoring at least 90 points

for( o = 0; o <= 90; o++ )
{
    input =get user input for score
    n++
    o += input 
}   
percentage = n/o *100
output percentage
```

Have I correctly understood the question criteria?

EDIT Answer Attempt 1 :-

```
int numGames = 0;           //number of games
int numTotalPoints = 0;     //total number of games scoring
int userInput =0;           //to Track input if negative number is enterred
double average = 0.0            //to get average of the game
double gameTo90Points =0.0; //calculate total games to reach 90 points
double percentage 0.0;          //to calculate the percentage

Text.put("Input the game score");
userInput = text.getInt;

while(userInput >= 0  )
    {
        numTotalPoints += userInput;
        numGames++;
        Text.put("Input the game score");
        userInput = text.getInt;
    }

if(numGames = 0)
    {
        Text.put("Not enough score to tabulate");
    }
    else
    {
        average = ((double)numTotalPoints)/numGames); 
        gameTo90Points = 90/average;
        percentage = (gameTo90Points/90)*100
        Text.put("Total number of games :" +numGames);
        Text.put("Total number of games scoring at least 90 points:" +gameTo90Points);
        Text.put("Percentage of games scoring at least 90 points:" +percentage);

    }
```

Comment: What does `get user input for score` stand for? In practice, this is usually not viable. Instead you have a `get user input` and you need to go from there.

Comment: Your input loop should not stop when the sum is 90, but when the user enters a sentinel value. The value of 90 serves another purpose in the question. It is a condition to add it to one of the statistics you are asked to collect; it has nothing to do with the number of loop-iterations you need to perform.

Comment: @trincot, i've already edited my answer for my first attempt . Please assist to see whether im doing it wrongly or not

Comment: up, anyone for takers?

Comment: Need assistance tq

Comment: anyone to assist me for clarification?

Comment: Anybody out there?

Comment: There's a lot of view and nobody can assist me

Comment: anybody out there for assistance?

Answer (score 2):

As this is a task you must complete, we should not provide you with the answer to that assignment.

I will provide some comments on your current pseudo-code.

> ```
> n = 0 // number of games
> o = 0 // total number of games scoring at least 90 points
> ```

So far this is a good start, but it is better to use variable names that actually tell something about it (e.g. `numGames`, `numHighScoringGames` would be good candidates). Also, the assignment asks to *"figure out the type of each variable"*. This is something you have not done yet...

> ```
> for( o = 0; o <= 90; o++ )
> ```

This loop is wrong. After the loop finishes `o` will be a number greater than 90. But `o` is supposed to be a particular number of games (with a score of at least 90). This should trigger an alarm... You haven't read any input yet and you already seem to know there will be more than 90 of such games? That's not right.

The value of `o` should have nothing to do with whether the loop should continue or not.

> ```
> input =get user input for score
> ```

Again, the data type should be determined for the variable `input`.

> ```
> n++
> ```

This is good, but you did not take into account this part of the assignment:

> The user entering a negative sentinel value indicates the end of the input.

Your code should verify if the user entered a negative sentinel value. And if so, you should not ask for more input.

> ```
> o += input
> ```

The variable `o` is supposed to be a number of games, but now you are adding a score to it... that cannot be right. Also, you add it unconditionally... Should you not first check whether that game is *"scoring at least 90 points"*?

> ```
> percentage = n/o *100
> ```

Here you use `o` as it was intended (as a number of games). But think about this... which one of the two will be greater (when not equal)? `n` or `o`? Taking that answer into account: Is your formula correct?

Secondly, could the denominator be zero? Should you protect the code from it?

> ```
> output percentage
> ```

OK, but don't forget that the assignment asks for three statistics, not just one.

Comment: Noted mate, will revise the logic and thanks for helping to decipher the requirement. Now it seems i got the better picture.

Comment: i've already edited my answer for my first attempt . Please assist to see whether im doing it wrongly or not